# Uninstall Google chrome built-in plugins

Tags: google-chrome, flash, plugins

Is there a way to turn off permanently the plugins inside chrome? Especially, I am interested in the flash and video plugins. This causes a huge overload on my Internet , and it would be great if someone could suggest a way to uninstall or permanently turn-off these plugins.

Update:

I am specifically looking for a way to permanently disable the plugin with no way of resuscitation. I am dealing with hard data caps, so under no circumstance do I want any content to be played by others using the system. I know this sounds strange, but please help me out! Thank you in advance!

Comment: Please select a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Open a chrome tab, enter "**chrome://plugins**" on the address bar, then enter

[image]

- Find the "[+] Details" button in the upper right to show the details of each installed plugin and click this button.

[image]

You may disable the plugins as you. Also remember, by doing this will not harm in anyway since you're disabling but not be able to delete. Nevertheless, these are built-in plugins with chrome which associate with different websites & services as per the needs. Therefore, those websites or services may not display what you need to see (E.g.: if a web content needs flash plugin to access which will not work since disabled... etc). Disable it by acknowledging yourself as to what it will cause the web browsing.

Answer (score 0):

I use the following tweaks to minimize waste of power, bandwidth and nerves:
Install https://adblockplus.org/de/chrome .
Also enable click2play for the desired plugins: http://www.2ality.com/2012/08/chrome-click-to-play.html

Answer (score 0):

You can go delete/remove the extensions in the settings page of chrome.

Removing flash and those types of plugins is done by going to chrome://plugins and disabling it there.

Comment: I am familiar with disabling the plugins. But it's not a permanent change. Anyone can enable it later! How do I do this for good?